# Meta field for Domain Url? Or is it possible to change the index of google

Tags: google, meta-tags

So I did the misstake of using a temporary url a while ago when launching my web site and called it http://web.mysite.com

Now when google indexes it, even that the web. is not the primary url anymore it still uses that over the http://www.mysite.com

Is there any way I can change this? Unfortunately I cant remove the web.mysite.dom binding from IIS since all Google links refer to that and I cannot use wildcard binding on the actual server.

I have google analytics enabled with the correct url (www.mysite.com).

Is there a way to enter some kind of meta data that enforces the robots to see the address as www.mysite.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you implement google webmaster tools it does give you some options over how the domain is displayed but I don't know if it would help your particular situation.

Comment: Thanks, I've implemented it. I'll get back in a day or two if this solved the problem.